# 'To' vs 'that'?

Tags: grammaticality

We have a suite of software products. Should our tagline be:

Tools **to** bring content to life

or:

Tools **that** bring content to life

Comment: Both are sentence fragments that can be used in whichever way you prefer.  The former implies that the tools are being provided, but the creator is providing the ability.  Whereas the latter implies that the tools in themselves contain the ability.

Comment: @Zibbobz Your comment teases out a subtlety that warrants an answer.

Comment: @bib Usually I try to keep short answers to a comment, but at your request, I've expanded a little bit upon it and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both are sentence fragments that can be used in whichever way you prefer.  When creating a slogan for a product, full sentences are not required.  However, they do have different meanings.

"Tools to bring content to life" implies that the tools are being provided, but the creator is providing the ability.

Whereas "Tools that bring content to life" implies that the tools in themselves contain the ability.

The tagline you choose should therefore be based on which implication you want to convey.

Comment: I agree with Zibbobz

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine grammatically and essentially have the same meaning.

For use in a tagline, I would choose the first one because:

1. The alliteration in "*t*ools" and "*t*o" sounds nice and reads more quickly when spoken aloud.
2. Using "**to**" saves two letters (better fit on billboards, bumper stickers and Tweets).
3. Using "**to**" twice gives the whole phrase a visual symmetry and draws the eyes to the more important keywords "*tools*", "*content*" and "*life*".

Comment: Great reasons! I like it. 'To' it is then.